# AppController::redirect() not working in CakePhp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-1.3

I have a redirect in a view that was working correctly under CakePHP 1.2. I just upgraded to 1.3, and this one page redirect quit working.  I'm assuming it's something simple, but couldn't find anything about it in the migration documentation.

in my views\about\index.ctp, I have this line:

```
AppController::redirect("howitworks/index");
```

When I hit that about/index page, I get this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Component
>   [CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line 678]
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function beforeRedirect() on a
>   non-object in "{localaddress}"\cake\libs\controller\controller.php on
>   line 678

I cannot simply route the page, because the redirect is part of an if sequence where if the controller does not supply any text to the .ctp, it redirects away to this other page.  I stripped out all that code so that only the redirect remained, to be sure this was the problem.

Can you direct me how to fix this please?

Comment: For clarification - I can access howitworks/index directly with no problems if I type it into my address bar.

Comment: Redirecting is usually done in the controller, not in the view, so I would reconsider your approach.

Comment: @dhofstet , I considered that that might be the problem.  It's the if sequence that makes me want to leave it (and it DID work in 1.2).  If the .ctp does not receive $text from the controller, it redirects.  I'll re-write the code into the controller if I need to, but I'd like to understand why it worked in 1.2 and not 1.3 then.

Comment: @dhofstet , if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it to mark this as answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as @dhofstet suggested, and just rewrote it so the redirect is in the controller.
Not sure why the original worked, but it is cake practice to redirect in the controller, as he said.